# Android LocaleUtils.isAvailableLocale ExceptionInInitializerError for en_US locale

Tags: android, exception, locale

I'm getting weird crashes (from Fabric.io logs) on Samsung Galaxy S8 and S8 Plus devices with Android 7.0. I'm trying to validate the newly created `Locale (en_US)` but I'm getting `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {

    // Save the original locale for logs and other stuff
    private Locale mOriginalLocale;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The current locale is en_US
        mOriginalLocale = Locale.getDefault();

        // Update the user's locale
        updateLocale();
    }

    private void updateLocale() {
        // Retrieve the user's saved settings from app. For e.g: en_US
        String country = getSettings().getCountry();
        String language = getSettings().getLanguage();

        // Create the new locale
        Locale locale = new Locale(language, country);

        // Check if the locale is valid
        boolean isValidLocale = LocaleUtils.isAvailableLocale(locale);

        // If it's not a valid locale, then remove the country, use only the language
        if (!isValidLocale) {
            locale = new Locale(language); 

            // Validate again
            if (!LocaleUtils.isAvailableLocale(locale)) {
                // Still not a valid locale, fallback to original locale
                locale = getDefaultLocale();
            }
        }

        // Update the device's locale
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = app.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
        }
        else {
            configuration.locale = locale;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            app.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        } else {
            res.updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
        }
    }    
}
```

The code crashes right after calling `boolean isValidLocale = LocaleUtils.isAvailableLocale(locale);`with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getAllAvailableLocales(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:203)
    at java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales(Locale.java:1004)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.a$a.<clinit>(LocaleUtils.java:324)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.a.a(LocaleUtils.java:222)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.a.a(LocaleUtils.java:247)
```

I don't know what to do. If the Device current locale is already `en_US` why can't be validated by `apache`'s utility method? Is a bug in their library? What alternatives can you give me?